# Filter by largest and smallest values in data frame by column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I created this data frame with station IDs and respective counts. Now I want to find the 10 largest values and the 10 smallest values in this data frame and save them in a new data frame.

```
station_activity <- tripdata %>% count(start.station.id)
station_activity <- station_activity %>% filter(n > 6100 & n < 100)
```

Line 1 was used to create the data frame seen in the picture and line 2 was used to filter by the values, but that does obviously result in an empty data frame. Is there a better version to do so, without writing a long conditional code?

[image: Dataframe to be filtered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition should be `OR` (`|`) and not `AND` (`&`) as a value can't be both greater than 6100 and less than 100

```
library(dplyr)
station_activity %>% 
   filter(n > 6100 | n < 100)
```

If we want to get the top 10 and bottom 10, `arrange` by the 'n' column from the `count`, and `slice` the first 10 and last 10 rows

```
tripdata %>% 
   count(start.station.id) %>%
   arrange(n) %>%
   slice(c(head(row_number(), 10), tail(row_number(), 10)))
```

Comment: Is there a better version to do so, without previously having to count the threshold by hand?